# Difference between init and initWithID

Tags: xml

Can someone explain to me what this line does?

```
XMLParser *parser1 = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParserWithID:1];
```

How can I check the ID in XMLParse?

Answer (score 0):

`alloc` allocates memory for objects, initialisers set them to a default state.  Some objects need extra information to be set up properly, so their initialisers have arguments.  In this case, `XMLParser` objects need an ID number to be set up correctly, so its initialiser has an argument where you can pass that number in.

> How can I check the ID in XMLParse?

Can you reword this or give an example of what you would like to do?  It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to check in XMLParser.m which Viewcontroller called the parser function!